# Hello Friends, How can I access the data of the array in the object?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
var obj = {};
let _list = []; 
obj[row[${'sub_field'}].split(".").shift()] = res.data.data 
_list.push(obj) 
setTypeList(_list);
```

I have a code like this, I throw the data returned as a result of the request to the object with the key and then I throw the state in the form of an array

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQcxu.png)

when ı made to typeList[0]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbZBb.png)

ı want to access operation_type, ı tried typeList[0]["operation_type"], ı got an error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. Because `operation_type` also have two options.

```
typeList[0].operation_type[0]
```

If you still receive **error** please share the error message.

Comment: I'm so sorry for being late. operation_type is object key and in the listenter image description here

and ı'm getting an error. ×
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'operation_type')

Comment: ı'm found my error.  The operation_type object cannot currently be found in state. ı fill state in dropdown onChange event